# Spring batch partition or using java multi threading?

Tags: spring-batch

Need to design multi threading with Spring batch. Spring batch partition or using java multi threading, Which one is a better choice? We have many processes, each process holds jobs and sub jobs. these sub jobs needs to be executed in parallel.How can I do the retry mechanism in partition??

Answer (score 0):

Go for the partition with master-slave concept. I have tried this and it boots the performance in good amount.

Restart Scenario :

1. Once your partitioner starts and your items are divided to the slaves.
   Lets say you have 3 slaves and each slave holds 1 file to process.
   Manually delete some items in the file which is assigned to the Slave2 so that it should get failed(Either in reader or writer of your slave step).
2. Then restart the job. Now it should start reading from the file which was assigned to the Slave2.